# kbreakout error qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, archlinux, kde-plasma, manjaro

Hello I'm trying to run `kbreakout` (Kde game), but I got these error.
Do you know what it is?

`./kbreakout`

> No protocol specified
>   qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
>   qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
>   This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)